# Show that the sum Ker(T) + R(T) is a direct sum of subspaces Ker(T) and R(T).

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field F where $1 + 1 + 1 \neq 0_F$. Let $T_i: V \to V$ $(i = 1,2)$ be two linear operators. Assume that $T_1 \circ T_1 = T_1$, $T_2 \circ T_2 = 3T_2$ and $T_1 \circ T_2 = 0 I_v = T_2 \circ T_1$ where $0 I_v$ is the zero map. It is know that $T := T_1 + T_2$ is a linear operator on V.

Show that the sum Ker(T) + R(T) is a direct sum of subspaces Ker(T) and R(T).

My solution:
I have to prove that the intersection is {0}. So suppose there is a $u \in v$ such that $ u\in Ker(T)$ and $u \in R(T)$. Then we have T(u) = 0 and u = T(w) for some $w \in v$. $0 = T(0) = T(T(u)) = (T_1 + T_2)(T_1 + T_2)(u)$ (*) $= (T_1 + 3T_2)(u) = (T + 2T_2)(u) = 2T_2(u)$

Hence, $T_2(u) = 0$

$T_2(u) = T_2(T(w)) = T_2(T_1 + T_2)(w) = T_2(T_2)(w) = 3T_2(w) = 0$

Hence, $T_2(w) = 0$

From above (*), $(T_1 + 3T_2)(u) = (T_1 + 3T_2)(T_1 +T_2) (w) = (T_1 + 9T_2)(w) = 0$

Hence, $T_1(w) = 0$

Therefore, $u = (T_1 + T_2)(w) = 0$ Hence the result

Comment: From $2T_2(u) = 0$ it does not necessarily follow that $T_2(u) = 0$; your field may be of characteristic 2.